# How to Prove that this Function is not $1-1$

Tags: calculus, inverse

I'm trying to show that the function

$$f(x)= \dfrac{x}{4}+x^2\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)$$
is not $1-1$ for any neighborhood of $0$. I know that what I have to do is find two different points that yield the same value, but these are not so obvious.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think OP here means to show that it is injective, or one-to-one.

Comment: @Rob Arthan  Thanks I have deleted my comment.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of $f(x)$ is

$$f'(x)=\frac 14+2x\sin\left(\frac 1x\right)-\cos\left(\frac 1x\right)$$

In any neighborhood of zero, you can find a very small positive $a$ where $\cos\left(\frac 1a\right)=1$. Then the second term of my expression for $f'(a)$ is near zero, thus $f'(a)$ is near $-\frac 34$, thus $f'(a)$ is negative, thus $f(x)$ is decreasing in a neighborhood of $a$ that is inside our neighborhood of zero.

In that same neighborhood of zero, you can find a very small positive $b$ where $\cos\left(\frac 1b\right)=-1$. Then the second term of my expression for $f'(b)$ is near zero, thus $f'(b)$ is near $\frac 54$, thus $f'(b)$ is positive, thus $f(x)$ is decreasing in a neighborhood of $b$ that is inside our neighborhood of zero.

Both $a$ and $b$ are positive, so $f(x)$ is continuous on the interval between $a$ and $b$. You can easily show that any function continuous on an interval that increases in a subinterval and also decreases in a subinterval is not injective on that interval. (Use the Intermediate Value Theorem on the four cases $a<b$ or $b<a$, $f(a)<f(b)$ or $f(b)<f(a)$). This is a useful theorem to use in many other problems, as well.

Thus your function $f(x)$ is not injective in any neighborhood of zero, in the positive part of that interval alone.

Answer (score 0):

Take any interval $(-\epsilon, \epsilon )$. Then, since $f'(x)=\frac{1}{4}+2x\sin \frac{1}{x}-\cos \frac{1}{x}$, we may choose $x\in (0,\epsilon )\ $such that $\cos \frac{1}{x}=1$ and $\sin \frac{1}{x}=0\Rightarrow f'(x)<0$.

On the other hand, we may also choose $y\in (0,\epsilon)$ so that $\cos \frac{1}{y}=0\Rightarrow f'(y)>0$. Wlog $x<y$. Since $f$ is differentiable on $(x,y)$, it has a local minimum at some point $c\in (x,y)$ and now an application of the Intermediate Value Theorem to the intervals $(x,c)$ and $(c,y)$ gives the result.

Answer (score -3):

When $-\frac 1n<x<\frac 1n$ the argument of $\sin (\frac 1x)$ takes all the values of the interval $]n,\infty[$ so that $\sin (\frac 1x)$ takes infinitely many times all the values of the rank $[-1,1]$ of the function $\sin x$ (If you want to draw the graph of $\sin (\frac 1x)$, you have a shaded rectangle in the neighborhood of $0$).

This is the reason for which the function $g(x)=x^2\sin (\frac 1x)$ can't be 1−1 for any neighborhood of $0$ and so is for $f(x)=\frac x4 +x^2\sin(\frac 1x)$.

Comment: The last line is certainly incorrect, since $|f(x)| \le \frac14|x| + |x|^2$. The argument before it isn't rigorous.

Comment: True. I deleted the last line

Comment: The answer is still not correct. It's not even rigorous for $x^2\sin\frac1x$, although at least it gets the right answer. But notice that your answer would also argue that $2x+x^2\sin\frac1x$ isn't one-to-one in a neighborhood of $x=0$—but it actually is.

Comment: The deleted last line was clearly a distraction (forgot the factor $x^2$) but now I do not agree with you. Do not forget neither that it is not $0$ but a neighborhood of $0$ nor the "if and only if" respect of the interval $]n,\infty[$.  I responded to a student reputation 1 and what interests me most is to teach young people (the little I know despite having a French doctorate in elliptic curves). You can put more downvotes if you want (I'm not at all interested in reputation points and if you don't believe me about this, it would be your problem not mine). Regards, sincerely.